# Cross-Origin Request Blocked between Node dev server and Spring Boot application

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring, cross-domain

My stack is as follows:

Backend: Spring boot(Java) exposed at :8088

Frontend: Vue hosted on a Node development server exposed at :8080

On the frontend, I am re-configuring `axios` in a `http-common.js` to put the baseURL to the Spring boot application, and allow connection from the node development server:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const AXIOS = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8088`,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'
  }
})
```

However, when attempting to make a `post` request to log in, I will get the following message in the console:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8088/api/login. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).`

Which makes me think: Is the issue with the spring boot application?

But no, in the main method, I have enabled CORS globally when reaching the `/api/*` endpoints from the node application running at :8080:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() { // Enables CORS globally
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

To me it looks as if it should be configured correctly. However, as of now, the following POST of username + password never even reaches the backend Spring boot application at all. The issue must be with the Node application?

This is the Login method in the frontend:

```
login ({commit}, authData) {
      AXIOS.post('/api/login', {
        username: authData.username,
        password: authData.password,
        withCredentials: true
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          commit('authUser', {
            token: res.data.idToken,
            userId: res.data.localId
          })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

To further solidate my point, i can cURL to the spring boot application and get the correct response(a valid JWT!):

Request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
        "username": "sysadmin",
        "password": "sysadmin"
        }' http://localhost:8088/api/login
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:8088
authentication: <very long JWT string>
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

So, via cUR  - I get a HTTP 200 OK, and a valid JWT. But via the same POST method from :8080, I get a 403 and a warning message.

As per other posts, I have attempted to add CORS to my dev server configuration(Node/Express):

```
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8088')

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next()
})
```

The result is exactly the same as previously

[image: Screenshot of response headers]

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to your ajax post call is useless since is part of cors specification and must be set by the server as part of the http response.

```
export const AXIOS = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8088`,
  headers: {
    //you can remove this header
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'
  }
})
```

You can curl the application because the cors exception is caused by the browser disallowing you to access the payload. The browser performs the preflight (OPTION) request before any Cross domain call, and before your actual http request to make sure you have the rights to see the payload, you can see it just inspecting the console under the network tab.

the issue is most likely server side, somehow you did not configure correctly the cors header to your http response.

make sure you're setting not only the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (that must contain the specific domain, not * since you're in credential mode), but even Access-Control-Allow-Credential since you're sending credentials, and the Access-Control-Allow-Methods (that must contain at least the PUSH and the OPTION methods)

in your chrome dev tools console under the network tab if you inspect your ajax call you can see the header of the http response,  should end up with something like this.

[image]

Comment: You are right, I just inspected in chrome and the response headers are similar to the ones you write there. Not sure where to add your things though.

Comment: If you see the configuration of Express in the original post, I have set the elements you describe(origin, credential, methods), but to no avail

Comment: it's important to see what is actually dowloaded by the client, you must have the above headers otherwise chrome won't forward the response to your app

Comment: there's an error, allow is not an header, actually all the values under 'allow' must be under Access-Control-Allow-Methods, the important one is OPTION that now is missing and is blocking the browser to make its request

Comment: That's strange. in my express app I have: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')`

Comment: Can't seem to change the access-control-allow-methods anywhere in the Express settings, it's stuck with POST somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160081/discussion-between-cbll-and-karim).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add @CrossOrigin to your login REST method?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

**Update:** I just read this on javadoc:

> Exact path mapping URIs (such as "/admin") are supported as well as Ant-style path patterns (such as "/admin/**").

I don't see here a path with one star, but your path is a correct Ant-style path..

Comment: To my knowledge, that isn't necessary if it's already configured as a bean in the main method(should enable it globally). But I will try it. Though, it never reaches the server at all and the response is empty, so i dont think the issue is on the java side?

Comment: I tried your way, the result is the same, as I suspect the POST never even reaches the REST endpoint, so it is definitely an issue with the node/express dev server

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint at the registry.addMapping() method? Just to be sure that this method gets hitted. By the way i made a mistake its @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080") and not @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8088")

Comment: Yeah I caught that. Where is the registry supposed to be?

Comment: Nothing wrong with how you did this. By the way can you try to use /api/** or /api/login and not /api/*. But I'm not sure if this changes anything but this is how i found it in some tutorials.